# AWS Database migration Service - Transformation Rule to drop column not working for DocumentDB

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, database-migration, aws-dms, aws-documentdb

I have DMS task that includes a transformation rule that should simply drop a column in target DocumentDB (my source is also DocumentDB), the structure of document is like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "999",
    "canceledAt": {"$date": "2020-12-08T05:14:57.952Z"},
    "createdAt": {"$date": "2016-03-14T16:43:21.075Z"},
    "emails": [
      {
        "verified": false,
        "address": "haha@mail.com"
      }
    ],
    "referralCode": "PPP",
    "referredBy": {
      "betaSignupId": "best",
      "referralCode": "code"
    },
    "roles": {
      "product": []
    },
  }
]
```

I would like to drop emails and roles during DMS task, so I have this mapping JSON:

```
{
    "rules": [
        {
            "rule-type": "transformation",
            "rule-id": "123",
            "rule-name": "12",
            "rule-target": "column",
            "object-locator": {
                "schema-name": "lol",
                "table-name": "users",
                "column-name": "emails"
            },
            "rule-action": "remove-column",
            "value": null,
            "old-value": null
        },
        {
            "rule-type": "transformation",
            "rule-id": "1234",
            "rule-name": "124",
            "rule-target": "column",
            "object-locator": {
                "schema-name": "lol",
                "table-name": "users",
                "column-name": "roles"
            },
            "rule-action": "remove-column",
            "value": null,
            "old-value": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Unfortunately it still keeps **roles** and **emails** in target DocumentDB. My guess columns value should be in different format but I can't quite figure out which. Thanks for help!